# Equivalent integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prove that a differential equation of the form:
$$ x' = A(t)x + f(t,x(t)) $$
with initial condition $x(0) = x_0$ is equivalent to the integral equation:
$$ x(t) = X(t,t_0)x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} X(t,s) f(s, x(s)) ds $$
where $X(t,s)$ is the principal solution of the lineal equation $x'= A(t)x$.

I am having problems to interpret why $X$ depends on two parameters, and not just on $t$.

I have tried to deduce the formula in the same way I would do for the usual differential equation ($x' = f(t,x)$) but I don't get similar results at all.

My attempt:
The problem $x' = A(t)x + f(t,x(t))$ is equivalent to the integral equation:
$$ x(t) = x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} A(t) + f(s,x(s)) ds = x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} A(t)x(t) ds + \int^t_{t_0} f(s,x(s)) ds  $$
I don't really know how to go on from this point.

Comment: Are you sure, that the $x_0$ in the first term is correct? It should be included in the principal solution.

Comment: @MachineLearner I think it is alright, my profesor used this formula some times and he always wrote it like that.

Comment: The principal solution has the unit of $x$ and $x_0$ has the unit of $x$. Hence, the product has the unit of $x$^2.  but the left hand side has only the unit of $x$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @MachineLearner I don't think I'm understanding you. I think $X (t_0, t_0) = 1$ so if you evaluate in $t_0$ the result of both sides is indeed $x_0$.

Comment: The equation should hold for arbirary units of $x$. If the unit of $x$ is meters, then the resulting equation makes no sense.

Comment: @MachineLearner My profesor used this equation multiple times, I don't think it is wrong. To assist interpreting the meaning of $X$, for the linear case $x' = Ax$ we have $X(t,s) = e^{A(t-s)}$ as the associated matrix. We have then that $x(t) = X(t,t_0) x_0$ is the solution for the linear PIV, which is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X(t,t_0)$ is a propagator, $x(t)=X(t,t_0)x(t_0)$, it transports a state $x(t_0)$ from time $t_0$ to time $t$ according to the ODE system $x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$. As such, $X(t_0,t_0)=I$, $X(t,t_0)X(t_0,s)=X(t,s)$

Interchanging the role of the time points, the function $y(t)=X(t_0,t)x(t)$ is a constant for any solution of the homogeneous DE, in consequence $0=\partial_2X(t_0,t)x(t)+X(t_0,t)x'(t)\implies \partial_2X(t_0,t)=-X(t_0,t)A(t)$.

Now keep the propagator $X$ but change $x$ to the solution of $x'=Ax+f$. Then $y(t)=X(t_0,t)x(t)$ can be expected to mainly be proportional to $f$.
\begin{align}
y'(t)&=\partial_2X(t_0,t)x(t)+X(t_0,t)x'(t)
\\
&=-X(t_0,t)A(t)x(t)+X(t_0,t)(A(t)x(t)+f(t,x(t)))
\\
&=X(t_0,t)f(t,x(t))
\\
&=X(t_0,t)f(t,X(t,t_0)y(t))
\end{align}
Integration of this gives
\begin{align}
y(t)-y(t_0)&=\int_{t_0}^tX(t_0,s)f(s,x(s))\,ds
\\
x(t)&=X(t,t_0)\left[y(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^tX(t_0,s)f(s,x(s))\,ds\right]
\\
&=X(t,t_0)x(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t X(t,s)f(s,x(s))\,ds
\end{align}
as claimed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain what is a propagator? That term didn't come up in our lectures. It is a function such that every solution of the system $x'(t)$ can be written in the form $x(t) = X(t,t_0) x_0$ for the corresponding $x_0$?

Comment: That's just a name physics has given these types of operator families that connect the solution fibers over different time points according to some linear ODE. In quantum dynamics these serve to actually propagate particles, taking for the linear system the uncoupled version of the model.